# How to connect points with lines ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I want to connect the dots corresponds to each year with a line.
The dataframe:

```
canc_noncanc_df <- data.frame(
  Airline_Name = as.character(c("AA", "AS", "B6","CO", "DH", "DL", "EV", "FL", "HA", "HP", "MQ", 
  "NW", "OH", "OO", "TZ", "UA", "US", "WN", "XE", "AA", "AS", "B6", "CO", "DH", "DL", "EV", "F9", 
  "FL", "HA", "HP", "MQ", "NW", "OH", "OO", "TZ", "UA", "US", "WN", "XE")),
  Flights_per_Airline = as.numeric(c("686146", "163322", "89323", "297431", "256668", "676921", "271319", "160545", "47915", "192831", "465301", "501276", "359730", "453664", "74816", "549264", "413140", "980301", "361600", "663817", "155470", "110162", "293922", "133615", "640571", "290747", "53080", "192944", "48114", "195366", "515286", "473895", "369967", "507815", "43601", "479622", "417183", "1027275", "394414")),
  Cancelflight_per_Airline = as.numeric(c("3861", "2535", "482", "403", "3435", "5160", "3038", "719", "111", "2109", "8257", "2888", "7460", "4680", "265", "3848", "3673", "5978", "450", "2434", "2164", "888", "500", "1199", "6578", "7126", "77", "923", "64", "1623", "8020", "4026", "5696", "3848", "184", "3288", "4075", "5210", "1429")),
  Cancellation_rate = as.numeric(c(0.005627082, 0.015521485, 0.005396147, 0.001354936, 0.013383047, 0.007622751, 0.011197152, 0.004478495, 0.002316602, 0.010937038, 0.017745502, 0.005761297, 0.020737776, 0.010316005, 0.003542023, 0.007005739, 0.008890449, 0.006098127, 0.001244469, 0.003666673, 0.013906220, 0.008060856, 0.001701132, 0.008973543, 0.010268963, 0.024509281, 0.001450641, 0.004783771, 0.001330174, 0.008307484, 0.015564172, 0.008495553, 0.015395968, 0.007577563, 0.004220087, 0.006855399, 0.009767896, 0.005071670, 0.003623097)), 
  Year = as.factor(c(2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005))
)
```

The code I use:

```
ggplot(aes(y = cancellation_rate, x = Airline_Name, color = as.factor(Year)), data = canc_noncanc_df) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point")
```

The output I got:
[image]

The output I want to have:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close -- just add `geom_line` with `group = Year` and you are good to go:

```r
canc_noncanc_df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Airline_Name, y = Cancellation_rate, color = as.factor(Year))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Year))
```

[image]